# For Verilog/VHDL simulation: how to open modelsim wlf file from command line?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, modelsim

With GtkWave I can simply open a vcd waveform file from the command line as follows:

```
PS> gtkwave waves.vcd
```

Now, I'm needing to switch to modelsim, and need this feature as well.  How can I open a modelsim wlf waveform file from the command line and have it open a waves window the same way as gtkwave?  I want to do something like this:

```
PS> start vsim -do "wave open vsim.wlf"
ERROR: bad tcl syntax...
```

The best I can do so far is just open the wave window:

```
PS> start vsim -do "view wave"
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `-view` option of modelsim:

```
vsim -view vsim.wlf
```

will open the traced dataset in modelsim, there you can

```
do wave.do
```

to open your waveform file.

You can also do all of this together

```
vsim -view vsim.wlf -do wave.do
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `vsim -view vsim.wlf` ,then `add wave -r *`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `vsim -do my_module.do` where `my_module` looks like this:

```
vsim -gui work.my_module
add wave -position insertpoint  \
sim:/my_module/*
```

#### OR

You can use `vsim -gui work.my_module` directly, if you have added your design to work using:

```
vlib work
vcom my_module.vhd
vmap -c 
vsim -gui work.my_module
```